# Manhua about a Manhua artist trying to survive the apocalypse

Tags: story-identification, manga

I remember this manhua where the main character is a manhua artist. He went on a blind date where the girl told him the world would end, but he didn't believe until a monster attacked.  I'm not sure about the last part.

[image: close-up on character's face, musing, with the thoughts captioned: "As a manhua artist, I am sure of the quality of my works. I, however, am unable to guarantee that my readers' brains are working normally. Let's head back to our main event. The blind date. How good would it be if it was a pretty lady today... I might not be able to catch the eyey of a pretty lady, though..."]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Is this a panel from the comic?